# Snowflake Record Last Updated By

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to perform a query for records of a table with an extra clause to exclude a user that the data has been last updated by without adding a new column? For example, I want to query for records that have not been last touched by my current user. Does Snowflake store and allow use of something like this behind the scenes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define "not been last touched"? Please give us examples with sample data and desired results

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa, what I mean by last touched is that a user ran an insert or update on some rows in the table. I'm looking for a query that returns all the rows that weren't touched by said user without adding a new column.

Comment: My guess is you will need to manually update a new column to meet this requirement